# check if program has finished in bash

Tags: bash

this is the command I need to know when it finishes

```
docker-compose run myapp myservice npm run next:build
```

When it finishes, it outputs:

```
> next build
Creating an optimized production build ...
> Using external babel configuration
> Location: "/usr/app/.babelrc"
Compiled successfully.
 ┌ /_app
 ├ /_document
 ├ /_error
 ├ /create
 ├ /hello
 ├ /list
 └ /lists
```

but it doesn't exit, it stays open for some reason. I need to run something else after that. What are my options using a bash script?

Comment: Can you get the PID? As long as there's a `/proc/$pid/` directory, it's running.

Comment: the process is finished, it just doesn't exit automatically. So it's hanging there forever even though it is finished

Comment: foreground or background? Maybe try a `wait` to harvest the zombie?

Comment: How do you realize that it is finished?

Comment: only way I know is it says "Compiled successfully", how can I listen for this event and quit the process?

Comment: It's better to fix why it's run forever. Can you share your docker stuff?